# How I can start JDeveloper for BPEL 11g in debug mode. It´s possible?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, soa, bpel

For OSB 11g in Eclipse is possible to start weblogic server in debug mode and finally executing the proxy services (adding breakpoints) in debug mode. How is possible to do it for bpel 11g?

Answer (score 0):

You can debug in BPEL with Oracle SOA Suite 12c
http://weblog.singhpora.com/2014/06/first-take-on-soabpm-suite-12c.html

Answer (score 0):

Start the SOA debugger in either of the following ways.

- Click the debugger icon above the SOA Composite Editor

  **OR**
- Right-click the SOA composite application in the Applications window, and select Debug.

[image]

To set a breakpoint on a reference binding component.

- Right-click the applicable reference binding component (for example, a web service or a database adapter), and select one of the breakpoint options.
  [image]